# How to mapping from monoalphabetic cipher in java?

Tags: java, encryption, mapping

> Encryption type being implemented: monoalphabetic cipher
>
> For example,
> step 1. -
> step 2. -
> step 3. -
>
> result : -

I want to encrypt the plaintext as above.
How do you approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this `plainText.charAt(i) - 'a'` as the index of cipher**

Example :

```
char[] cipher = "dstuvwxuzabcdefghiklmnopqr".toCharArray();

String plainText = "iloveyouz";

StringBuilder cipherText = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
    cipherText.append(cipher[plainText.charAt(i) - 'a']);
}

System.out.println("Encrypted : " + cipherText.toString());

char[] original = new char[cipher.length];
for (int j = 0; j < original.length; j++) {
    original[cipher[j] - 'a'] = (char) ('a' + j);
}

StringBuilder decryption = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
    decryption.append(original[cipherText.charAt(i) - 'a']);
}

System.out.println("Decrypted : " + decryption.toString());
```

Output :

```
Encrypted : zcfnvqfmr
Decrypted : iloveyouz
```

Note : *You can preprocess the `original` generation process.*

Comment: Voted up simply because this at least builds up a new string instead of trying to replace characters as commonly done (replacing `'i'` with `'z'` while there are still `'z'` characters in the string is of course error prone)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers. This method-to-mapping (encryption) was successful. However, there was a problem with the decoded code applying this. The result is output as an integer.

Please check the modified source code.

Comment: @mminaa Added both encryption and decryption